# Invalid Coulmn name exception for column name as ID in JDBCpagingItemReader Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am using spring batch version 3.0.3 release. I am facing  an issue regarding the ID column name which is the primary key in the table. When i am firing a simple sql statement like

```
Select ID,name from xxx table where 'condition'
```

I am getting an exception like InvalidColumnName 'ID' while using JDBCpagingItemReader. I think it is happening as ID is a keyword in oracle. Is there any workaround for such scenario. Has anyone any idea about this.
I have also tried with writing single quotes such as 'Id' and also tried with alias still getting the same error.

Comment: You could try enclosing the column name in quotes: `Select "ID"...`. There might also be a syntax error in the query; could you post the exact query and table definition?

Comment: ID is a perfectly legitimate column name in oracle.  I use it all the time.  However, oracle does not like the word `table` as a table name or table alias.  Also your where clause is suspect since it's just a string and not a proper predicate.

Comment: Sorry I might be very late to comment but, this query perfectly runs with JdbcCursorItemReader and also works fine on SqlDeveloper,the issue i am facing is with JdbcPagingItemReader only